# Kill a "live" Ractive data object

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

With RactiveJS, an object that is set as data to a Ractive becomes "live" because the library has added some handlers to detect changes in the data. However, if I wanted to use the same object in another location that does not use Ractive, like say:

```
var objectForModuleB = objectForModuleA.get();
```

Modifying `objectForModuleB` would affect the data in `objectForModuleA` because the objects are still "live". I work around it by "doing a stringify-parse" to remove the handlers (I'm working only with data. No compute functions and date objects.):

```
var objectForModuleB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectForModuleA.get()));
```

If been through the documentation over and over. So far, I have not come across something like this in the docs.

Comment: Are you referring to Array modification methods and are you using `magic: true` in the options? Can you provide more detail on the structure of the object and how you want it to behave? I'm just trying to separate issues with Ractive from javascript object reference issues

Comment: @martypdx I believe I'm not using magic mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1042).

You simply need deep clone. `$.extend` is the right tool for this. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` might also work - depending on your data - but it's slow. If you don't want to use jQuery, you can create your own function or just take it from jQuery's core.

If you only want to prevent sharing data between more ractive instances, you can use option functions (v0.5.x):

```
new Ractive({
    data: function () {
        return {
            x: 1,
            y: 2 
        };
    }
});
```

This way, new data will be created for each ractive instance.